# Image magnification techniques, clarification needed

Tags: ios, image-manipulation

Before i start reinventing the wheel, i thought i'd check here to see if there are known image magnification techniques people know and love?

I am thinking .. for each image, on finger tap, i'd pop up an enlarged version of the same image (part of probably). Can i get away with a single image (and actually magnify it) or should i just swap images as user moves his/her finger?

Does this sound reasonable or, is this too much of a brute force approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand of your question - you want to tap on a thumbnail and it transitions to the full size/ larger size.

Best way of the top of my head would be to have a UIImageview with it's content mode set to UIViewContentModeAspectFill.

add the image view with CGSize of say 50X50 -- then add a UITapGestureRecogniser on it that triggers a function that does something like this:

```
- (void)tapped:(id)sender{
    UIImageView *v = [(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender view];
    CGRect f = [v frame];
    f.size = CGSizeMake(200,200);//or whatever size
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f 
                     animations:^(){
                         [v setFrame:f];
                     }];
}
```

hope this helps

Cheers,

Michael